# Searching semantically tagged documents in MarkLogic

Tags: semantics, marklogic

Can any one please point me to some simple examples of semantic tagging and querying semantically tagged documents in `MarkLogic`?

I am fairly new in this area,so some beginner level examples will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "semantically tagged" do you mean regular XML documents that happen to have some triples in them? The discussion and examples at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/embedded are pretty good for that.

Start by enabling the triple index in your database. Then insert a test doc. This is just XML, but the `sem:triple` element represents a semantic fact.

```
xdmp:document-insert(
  'test.xml',
  <test>
    <source>AP Newswire</source>
    <sem:triple date="1972-02-21" confidence="100">
      <sem:subject>http://example.org/news/Nixon</sem:subject>
      <sem:predicate>http://example.org/wentTo</sem:predicate>
      <sem:object>China</sem:object>
    </sem:triple>
  </test>)
```

Then query it. The example query is pretty complicated. To understand what's going on I'd insert variations on that sample document, using different URIs instead of just `test.xml`, and see how the various query terms match up. Try using just the SPARQL component, without the extra `cts` query. Try `cts:search` with no SPARQL, just the `cts:query`.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
sem:sparql('
  SELECT ?country
  WHERE {
<http://example.org/news/Nixon> <http://example.org/wentTo> ?country
  }
  ',
 (),
 (),
 cts:and-query((
   cts:path-range-query( "//sem:triple/@confidence", ">", 80) ,
   cts:path-range-query( "//sem:triple/@date", "<",     xs:date("1974-01-01")),
   cts:or-query((
     cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), "AP Newswire"),
     cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), "BBC"))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are talking about enriching your content using semantic technology, that is not directly provided by MarkLogic.

You can enrich your content externally, for instance by calling a public service like the one provided by OpenCalais, and then insert the enrichments to the content before insert.

You can also build lists of lookup values, and then using cts:highlight to mark such terms within your content. That could be as simple as:

```
let $labels := ("MarkLogic", "StackOverflow")
return
  cts:highlight($doc, cts:word-query($labels), <b>{$cts:text}</b>)
```

Or with a more dynamic replacement using spraql:

```
let $labels := map:new()
let $_ := 
  for $result in sem:sparql('
    PREFIX demo: <http://www.marklogic.com/ontologies/demo#>

    SELECT DISTINCT ?label
    WHERE {
      ?s a demo:person. 
      {
        ?s demo:fullName ?label 
      } UNION {
        ?s demo:initialsName ?label 
      } UNION {
        ?s demo:email ?label 
      }
    }
  ')
  return
    map:put($labels, map:get($result, 'label'), 'person')
return
  cts:highlight($doc, cts:word-query(map:keys($labels)), 
    let $result := sem:sparql(concat('
      PREFIX demo: <http://www.marklogic.com/ontologies/demo#>

      SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p
      {
        ?s a demo:', map:get($labels, $cts:text), ' .
        ?s ?p "', $cts:text, '" .
      } 
    '))
    return
      if (map:contains($labels, $cts:text))
      then
        element { xs:QName(fn:concat("demo:", map:get($labels, $cts:text))) } {
          attribute subject { map:get($result, 's') },
          attribute predicate { map:get($result, 'p') },
          $cts:text
        }
      else ()   
  )
```

HTH!